# Apply force on gameObject from any direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ball type GameObject coming from `upside` to `Down` using `gameObject.tranform.translate`. I want to add force on gameObject from anywhere in `Middle` or in any `random position` many times until gameObject reaches target.

Could anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want, but I think [RigidBody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) is what you're looking for. You apply force to the rigidbody of your `GameObject`, giving the direction you want the `GameObject` to go to. 
For example:

```
gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.forward);
```

This will push the `GameObject` this script is attached to forward. You could apply force in any direction, like `Vector3.up`, `Vector3.down` etc.

Comment: If it answered your question, could you mark it as answered by clicking the green checkmark?